# Selecting rows with same value from different columns

Tags: php, mysql

Say I had a database storing data from recent football games with my friends. I'd store the names of my friends in each row in no particular order. How could I pull that data back out without having to go through each row looking for each value in every column?

Here's an example table:

```
gameID   player1     player2    player3   .......
1        John        Chance     Gordon
2        Jim         Gordon     John
3        Derek       Chance     Richard
```

How could I select the rows that John played in just based on if he was in any column? I'm planning on putting them into a PHP array and counting their appearances. What is the most efficient way of checking every columns without making something like:

```
$playerarray=array{'Derek','John','Gordon','Richard','Jim','Chance',....}
foreach($playerarray as $key => $value){
    //Is this even horribly inefficient?
    $sql = mysql_query(SELECT * from game_table WHERE player1='$value' OR player2='$value' OR player3='$value'...)
}
```

Comment: how many different friends/players you have?

Comment: In my problem, about 60 different players that can take up about 16 spots per game.

Comment: please add to the question if it is important the "position" of the player. for example if john is player2 is the same if john is player1 ?

Comment: No I don't believe it matters in my case. I mean, the last 6 players are a bit different than the first 10, but I would just repeat the best process there is.

Comment: can someone calculate how many different "teams of 16" can exist for 60 players? (and share the math formula perhaps?) is it 16^60 minus something ???

Comment: I would recommend to change your db schema, create tables for games, for players and one for the relations. For each game you would then have up to 16 rows in the relation table and your SQL queries become easier and way faster.

Comment: I actually do have a table that has a row for each player-to-gameID connection.

Comment: @Sharky Formula is `n! / ((n-r)! * r!)` and the result for `n=60` and `r=16` is about `1.5 * 10^14`.

Comment: @Kragalon Then why do you have this extra table (which complicates matters)?

Comment: @paul does that exclude the john,john,john,john...john etc team?

Comment: as Paul doesn't quite say, see normalisation

Comment: @Sharky Yes, this is WITHOUT repetition. Otherwise it would be around `8 * 10^15`.

Comment: @Paul hmm thats a big number. so i guess a bit mask is out of the question :D thnx for the formulas :D

Comment: Well, let me think about that ...   Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Well I'm using the combinations in my statistics and I thought it would be easier to group them when I get those statistics. Plus since each row has 16 columns I thought that it would be more efficient than going through 16 times more rows. Which is about around a million by the way.

Comment: No, in my experience, keeping the db schema as easy as possible is in most cases the best strategy. Add all the complexity you need in MySQL views or in your programming language (PHP). You want to keep the queries fast.

Comment: In this case, if you had three tables `game, player, relation` you could easily check the appearance for ALL players in a single query: `SELECT p.name, COUNT(*) FROM player p JOIN relation r on r.player_id = p.id GROUP BY p.id`. This results in a list of all 60 players along with the count of their appearance.

Comment: I'm sorry. I neglected the fact that the last 6 'players' are not stored in this other table. See, fooball analogy aside, I'm storing data from another game where it is a 5v5 matchup with 6 'players' that are banned out and thus dont have a row in this other table. The statistics I am making use this ban data as a key component and is possibly more important in my stats than who actually played.

Comment: That's just another complexity, might be just one additional table. Still, I'd recommend to keep it simple.

Comment: Okay. I think I can use some code that I already have to get the count for the first 10 players out of the way. The last 6 however is going to need another approach. I will try the answer below. Thanks for the help by the way. I was going to try and figure out how many combinations there were with 60 players and 16 slots but you blew me out of the water with that speed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL statement that you need is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM game_table WHERE CONCAT_WS(',', player1, player2, player3) LIKE '%John%'
```

This query will return all fields of the rows where John comes in: first the 3 players' columns are concatenated with commas, and then searched whether John is in it.

If you would just want to count them:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT gameID) as numberofmatches FROM game_table WHERE CONCAT_WS(',', player1, player2, player3) LIKE '%,John,%' OR CONCAT_WS(',', player1, player2, player3) LIKE 'John,%' OR CONCAT_WS(',', player1, player2, player3) LIKE '%,John'
```

Or if you want a list of all the players:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT player1 AS player FROM game_table) UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT player2 AS player FROM game_table) UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT player3 AS player  FROM game_table)
ORDER BY player
```

You could also combine this with the previous, which gives me exactly what you want (I think):

```
SELECT player,count(distinct gameID) as numberofgames FROM game_table t1 JOIN ((SELECT DISTINCT player1 AS player FROM game_table) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT player2 AS player FROM game_table) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT player3 AS player  FROM game_table) ORDER BY player) t2 WHERE t2.player=t1.player1 OR t2.player=t1.player2 OR t2.player=t1.player3 GROUP by t2.player
```

This returns you a table with the names of all the different players, including the number of games they played !

If you want to select only a certain person (John), do the following:

```
SELECT player,count(distinct gameID) as numberofgames FROM game_table t1 JOIN ((SELECT DISTINCT player1 AS player FROM game_table) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT player2 AS player FROM game_table) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT player3 AS player  FROM game_table) ORDER BY player) t2 WHERE (t2.player=t1.player1 OR t2.player=t1.player2 OR t2.player=t1.player3) AND t2.player='John' GROUP by t2.player
```

Comment: One thing, in my situation there are players that have names inside another name. For example: John and Johnathon. Their counts would get screwed up with the `LIKE '%John%'` setup. Would `EQUAL TO 'John'` work?

Comment: try the last query, there they will be seen as a separate person ! In the query with `LIKE`, it will not work since you will check if `John` is in the query `John,Chance,Gordon`, or in `Gordon,Jonathan,Other`. Also `EQUAL` would not work !

Comment: It seems to work well. If the 2nd query you posted worked for names containing other names, it would work perfect, as I am looping through the players in an earlier part of the code anyway. Is there a way to get that to look strictly for `'John'`?

Comment: I think the last query is better, since you only need one SQL-query and do the rest in php. But if you want the second to work, you need 3 `LIKE` conditions instead of 1: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT gameID) as numberofmatches FROM game_table WHERE CONCAT_WS(',', player1, player2, player3) LIKE '%,John,%' OR CONCAT_WS(',', player1, player2, player3) LIKE 'John,%' OR CONCAT_WS(',', player1, player2, player3) LIKE '%,John'`

Comment: I'm going to try both of them out to see what works best for me. I'll probably go with your suggestion. Thanks so much for your help! Checked and upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'IN' clause like:

```
$playerarray = array{'Derek','John','Gordon','Richard','Jim','Chance',....};
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * from game_table WHERE player1 IN (" . $value . ") OR player2 IN  (" . $value . ") OR player3 IN  (" . $value . ") OR player4 IN  (" . $value . ")");
```

Also, don't use mysql but mysqli functions as the first one is depricated.

Alternatively, or rather preferably, if there's alot of players (meaning: alot of columns) you would be better of changing the design of your database. Normalization should make things easier here.

Comment: Thanks! Is `IN` faster than my example?

Comment: Since you are not looping around the playerarray and only executing the select query once I'd say it is quicker. The query on it's own would be slower.